# How to replace " ' " the "&#039;" HTML character with Stringreplace

Tags: html, string, delphi, apostrophe

i use a code to get the HTML from a page and save it's strings
but these strings sometimes come with `&#039;` as the `'` character

im trying to replace it with the actual ' character and it doesn't seem to work
i've tried this lines to find the string but no results

```
  StringReplace(myString, '&#039;', char(39), [rfReplaceAll]);
  StringReplace(myString, char(39), '*', [rfReplaceAll]);

  aPos := Pos(myString, char(39));
  aPos := Pos(myString, '&#039;');
  aPos := Pos(myString, '&');
  aPos := Pos(myString, '#');
  aPos := Pos(myString, '039');
```

Apos is never > 0

```
  if aPos > 0 then
  begin
    // replace the string
  end;
```

Answer (score 4):

`StringReplace` does not work in-place. You must assign the result of the function to a(nother) string:

```
myOtherString := StringReplace(myString, '&#039', '''', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

Try that, and you'll see that `myOtherString` contains the proper format. Of course you can also do:

```
myString := StringReplace(myString, '&#039', '''', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

#### EDIT

IMO, the function `Pos` is easier to remember as:

```
function Pos(const Needle, Haystack: string): Integer;
```

So if you swap your parameters, it should work.

Comment: User wants to assign to myString in this instance

Comment: @David: See my addition.

Comment: Yes that's better now

Comment: thanks for your reponse, i didn't notice that StringReplace would return the value, it works great now, but now i wonder why Pos function doesn't get the Pos on that string

Comment: @user The first parameter of Pos() is the substring (the string you are searching for), the second is the string that possibly contains the substring.

Answer (score 3):

`StringReplace` is a function that returns the new value. You are ignoring that new value. You need:

```
myString := StringReplace(myString, ...);
....
```

The other part of your question concerns the use of `Pos`. The first parameter to `Pos` is the sub-string that you are searching for within the second parameter. So you have your parameters to `Pos` in reverse order.